# Prohibit unintentional ~ from F6 button

Tags: key-bindings, letter-case

I have a mapping to remove trailing whitespace, defined like this: `nnoremap <silent> <F6> :%s/\s\+$//<CR>''`. It works fine, except that if I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> before pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>, instead of doing what it should it seems to do <kbd>~</kbd>(switch case for character) for a bunch of characters where the cursor is placed.

**How can I prevent that from happening?**

**EDIT 1:**

I'm on Arch Linux latest updates as of 2017-04-28 with Vim 8.0, running in gnome-terminal. It's the same on all systems I've tested, but it's worth noting that I'm on a Swedish keyboard layout (EDIT: Just tested, and it's the same on en_US layout for me).

**EDIT 2:**

I've narrowed it down some. While F1–F4 are caught by my terminal (so can't say anything there), F5 produces 5 characters to switch case, F6 produces 7 characters to switch, F7 does 8 and F8 does 9. I've tried disabling my `.vimrc`, and that fixes the problem. I'll search through the config and report back when I find what caused it.

**EDIT 3:**

If I remove my .vimrc, Vi does it but Vim does not. What does that mean?

**EDIT 4, major finding:**

So I've found the line in my config that causes it. It's `noremap <Esc><Esc> :noh<CR>`. Still don't understand why, though. :/

Comment: Could you add info with what terminal you use, OS, if you use tmux/screen etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by the line `nnoremap <Esc><Esc> :noh<CR>`, and can be fixed by changing it to `nnoremap <Esc>a :noh<CR>` or some other regular character instead of Esc. No idea why though.

Also, `nvim` seems to deal with `<Esc>` in the correct way.

Comment: Even mapping only `<Esc>` causes this behaviour.

Comment: Related thread: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Can-I-map-double-lt-Esc-gt-lt-Esc-gt-lt-Esc-gt-td5585213.html

Answer (score 0):

Granted that I am running nvim and use Terminator, but for the very same purpose as described above I use: `nnoremap <silent> <F5> :let _s=@/<Bar>:%s/\s\+$//e<Bar>:let @/=_s<Bar>:nohl<CR>`. In order to isolate the matter I created a new .vimrc and added only the aforementioned line to the file. With both nvim (0.1.7) and Vim (8.0) I get the expected behavior (white space at end of line eliminated) and no characters changes case.

Edit: I changed to gnome-terminal, and the same appears there (i.e. everything work as expected).